# integrability and distributions

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $G$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ($n\geq1$), and $f$ a measurable function defined on $G$. Suppose for all test functions $\phi$ with support in $G$, we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{G}f(x)\Delta \phi(x)dx>-\infty,\end{equation}
where $\Delta$ is the Laplace operator. Can we conclude that 
$$\int_{G}f(x)dx>-\infty?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. $G=(0, 1)$ and $f(x) = - 1/x$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Can you please explain why \begin{equation}
\int_{G}f(x)\Delta \phi(x)dx>-\infty,\end{equation} for all test function $\phi$?

Comment: What is your definition of a test function? If its $C^\infty$ and compact support you have an integral of continuous function over compact set, which is finite.